# Ubuntu VM Hangs on Boot

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, vmware

I'm trying to boot to a Linux virtual machine in VMWare Workstation 10 for some web development work. I had some problems with the VM I was using. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu in a new VM, and after the install every time I boot I get the error message shown in the following screenshot. Can anyone shed some light on how to solve or troubleshoot this? I'm fairly new to Linux.

[image]